# Function from my homework returns 0 no matter what I do

Tags: c

Create a function that takes a number n as an argument and returns the largest integer that is less than or equal to n and has the highest digit sum.

Examples:

```
largestDigitSum(100) ➞ 99
// Digit Sum for 99 = 9 + 9 = 18
// All numbers from 0 to 98 and 100 itself have digit sum lesser than 18.

largestDigitSum(48) ➞ 48
// Digit sum for 48 = 4 + 8 =12
// Digit sum for 39 = 3 + 9 =12
// Return 48 because 48 > 39

largestDigitSum(10) ➞ 9
```

So basically I tried solving this problem but the function would return 0 no matter what I did. Here's my attempt at coding:

```
int largestDigitSum(int n)
{
    int s1 = 0, s2, c, maxi;
    while (n > 0) {
        c = n % 10;
        s1 += c;
        n /= 10;
    }

    while (n > 0) {
        n--;
        while (n > 0) {
            c = n % 10;
            s2 += c;
            n /= 10;
        }
        if (s1 > s2)
            maxi = n;
        else
            s1 = s2;
    }
    return maxi;
}
```

Can someone please explain what I did wrong?

Edit:

Ok, thanks to everyone who helped me understand this problem. I tried dividing it into 2 functions and now it works! Here's my new code:

```
int digitSum(int n)
{int s=0;

while(n>0)
    {s += n%10;
    n/=10;}

return s;
}

int largestDigitSum(int n)
{int i, maxi=1;

for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    if(digitSum(i) >= digitSum(maxi))
        maxi=i;
return maxi;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your observation.

Comment: What is the starting value of `maxi`?

Comment: Think about the value of `n` after the first loop has finished, and how many times the next loop will execute.

Comment: Also, don't leave any variables uninitialized.

Comment: Trying to write clearly will lead you thinking more clearly about a problem. And, before you instinctively claim that your style is clear to you, consider why no such style has ever gained widespread adoption. You can also just type without worrying about formatting by delegating that to a program. I use this https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format

Comment: After the first `while` loop, `n` has a value of zero, so the second and its nested loops are never executed.  `maxi` is uninitialised so the behaviour of your code is undefined  (it just so happens, with your compiler, that `maxi` has a value of zero, so your function returns zero, but that is not guaranteed).

Comment: You should stop chasing bugs that the compiler has already found and pointed out for you. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to separate the evaluation of the function you are maximizing from the actual process of seeking a maximum:

```c
static unsigned int
sum_of_digits(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This way, you can reason about the "sum of digits" function separately from any other logic.

I am interested in both the integer that gives me the desired result ([`argmax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max)) and the maximized value. Therefore, I declare a struct that can hold both values:

```c
struct max_result {
    unsigned int argmax;
    unsigned int max;
};
```

Now, I can write a function that seeks the maximized value of a another function in a range:

```c
static struct max_result *
max_value_of_function(
        unsigned int n,
        unsigned int (*fn)(unsigned int)
)
{
    unsigned int i = 1;

    struct max_result *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    assert(r);

    r->argmax = 0;
    r->max = 0;

    do {
        unsigned int s = fn(i);
        if (s >= r->max) {
            r->max = s;
            r->argmax = i;
        }

        if (i == n) {
            break;
        }

        ++i;
    } while (1);

    return r;
}
```

This means you can focus the logic of seeking the maximum independently of calculating the sum of the digits of a number.

When writing stuff like this, it is always useful to start with some test cases. No need to do anything fancy ... Something that compares expected output for a given input with the actual returned value of the function. I put in the cases listed in your question plus two other interesting cases.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct max_result {
    unsigned int argmax;
    unsigned int max;
};

struct test_case {
    const unsigned int input;
    const unsigned int expected;
};

static
int sum_of_digits(unsigned int n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}

static struct max_result *
max_value_of_function(
        unsigned int n,
        unsigned int (*fn)(unsigned int)
)
{
    unsigned int i = 1;

    struct max_result *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    assert(r);

    r->argmax = 0;
    r->max = 0;

    do {
        unsigned int s = fn(i);
        if (s >= r->max) {
            r->max = s;
            r->argmax = i;
        }

        if (i == n) {
            break;
        }

        ++i;
    } while (1);

    return r;
}

int
main(void) {
    int i;

    struct test_case cases[] = {
        { 0, 0 }, { 100, 99 }, { 48, 48 }, { 10, 9 }, { UINT_MAX, 3999999999U },
    };

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(cases)/sizeof(cases[0]); ++i) {
        struct max_result *r = max_value_of_function(cases[i].input, sum_of_digits);
        if (r->argmax == cases[i].expected) {
            printf(
                    "The positive integer with largest sum of digits in [0, %u] is %u\n"
                    "Sum of its digits is %u\n",
                    cases[i].input,
                    r->argmax,
                    r->max
            );
        }
        else {
            printf("Got %u ... expected %u\n", r->argmax, cases[i].expected);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int largestDigitSum(int n)
{
    int s1 = 0, s2, c, maxi;
    while (n > 0) {
        c = n % 10;
        s1 += c;
        n /= 10; // This loop will never end until n becomes 0
    }

    while (n > 0) { // n is 0 because of the last loop
        n--; // this will never enter
        while (n > 0) {
            c = n % 10;
            s2 += c;
            n /= 10;
        }
        if (s1 > s2)
            maxi = n; // this will never be called
        else
            s1 = s2;
    }
    return maxi; // maxi is never being initialized to begin with
}
```

`maxi` isn't even being initialized, so the fact that you see 0 is merely the result of undefined behavior. That's why this function returns 0 all the time.

Comment: if number has type of `int` you should not check numbers >0 only numbers >= INT_MIN

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll try solving it once more

Comment: If you divide a complex function into smaller ones, you'll have an easier time tackling the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. This task makes only sense if the input number is unsigned. If it is signed you should search until the INT_MIN (as anynumner >= INT_MIN).

use function for repeated tasks.

```
unsigned sumdigits(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned sum = 0;
    while(x) 
    {
        sum += x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

unsigned brutForce(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned cmax = 0, csum, maxnum;
    while(x)
    {
        csum = sumdigits(x);
        if(csum > cmax) {cmax = csum; maxnum = x;}
        x--;
    }
    return maxnum;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("Max number: %u\n", brutForce(100000));
}
```

Of course there are much more efficient ways of doing it.